# MySQL DATE_ADD throws Hibernate error

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using HQL with DATE_ADD (mysql function) as below

```
String hql = 
        "select count(*) " +
        "from ProgramGroupEvent as eventLog " +
        "where eventLog.id= :id" +
        "and DATE_ADD( eventLog.eventDate, INTERVAL :interval MINUTE) > now()"; 


    long count = 0;

    try {
        count = ((Long)sess.createQuery( hql )
            .setLong( "id", id)
            .setInteger("interval", interval )
            .iterate().next()).longValue();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But hibernate throws a token error as below

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: :
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4016) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:859) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3390) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
```

PS: I am using Hibernate 4.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did further research and found out the issue. The problem is Hibernate is not able parse the syntax. As per it's expectation, this is not well formed HQL syntax.
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=982317&view=previous

I fixed by replacing

```
DATE_ADD( eventLog.eventDate, INTERVAL :interval MINUTE) > now()";
```

With

```
time_to_sec(timediff( now() , eventLog.eventDate )) < :seconds";
```

Hopefully, this can help for someone

Answer (score 1):

Your query require two parametrs

- pharmacyOid
- interval

But in your query parameters **id** and **interval** are used.

Your query should look:

```
count = ((Long)sess.createQuery( hql )
        .setLong( "pharmacyOid", id)
        .setInteger("interval", interval )
        .iterate().next()).longValue();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340025/how-to-build-a-dynamic-query-which-add-number-of-days-to-date-and-compare-that-d